# views aren't getting updated in recycler list view every time. diff util object won't detect change the first time

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

A screen recording video [the log files were taken using the same exact actions] -

[screen-recording](https://youtu.be/hPD7pshj3G4)

[watch the recording for context] My problem is that the diffutil object in the adapter can't detect the changes being made the first time and so, the list elements dont get updated. At the right end of the log lines, you'll see a truth value table. the left column is supposed to be all false. but, look at the first value - true. the access values are supposed to be all false when I launch the app. and they are all false when I launch the app else the video wouldn't start with all passwords hidden when I launch the app. So, the first time the comparision isn't being made to the actual olditem. but, the changed olditem.

Log output for the adapter diff util object -

```
    • this is from the initial access. it reads the access. but cannot identify the changes that has been applied. ----making changes the first time -

2022-01-11 16:35:02.695 28084-28146/com.kenetic.savepass I/PassAdapter: id equality checked -   Service_name_1      access value passed -   true    true
2022-01-11 16:35:02.695 28084-28146/com.kenetic.savepass I/PassAdapter: id equality checked -   Service_name_2      access value passed -   false   false
2022-01-11 16:35:02.695 28084-28146/com.kenetic.savepass I/PassAdapter: id equality checked -   Service_name_3      access value passed -   false   false
2022-01-11 16:35:02.695 28084-28146/com.kenetic.savepass I/PassAdapter: id equality checked -   Service_name_4      access value passed -   false   false
2022-01-11 16:35:02.695 28084-28146/com.kenetic.savepass I/PassAdapter: id equality checked -   Service_name_5      access value passed -   false   false
2022-01-11 16:35:02.695 28084-28146/com.kenetic.savepass I/PassAdapter: id equality checked -   Service_name_6      access value passed -   false   false
2022-01-11 16:35:02.695 28084-28146/com.kenetic.savepass I/PassAdapter: id equality checked -   Service_name_7      access value passed -   false   false
2022-01-11 16:35:02.695 28084-28146/com.kenetic.savepass I/PassAdapter: id equality checked -   Service_name_8      access value passed -   false   false
2022-01-11 16:35:02.695 28084-28146/com.kenetic.savepass I/PassAdapter: id equality checked -   Service_name_9      access value passed -   false   false
2022-01-11 16:35:02.695 28084-28146/com.kenetic.savepass I/PassAdapter: id equality checked -   Service_name_10     access value passed -   false   false
2022-01-11 16:35:02.695 28084-28146/com.kenetic.savepass I/PassAdapter: id equality checked -   Service_name_11     access value passed -   false   false
2022-01-11 16:35:02.695 28084-28146/com.kenetic.savepass I/PassAdapter: id equality checked -   Service_name_12     access value passed -   false   false
2022-01-11 16:35:02.695 28084-28146/com.kenetic.savepass I/PassAdapter: id equality checked -   Service_name_12     access value passed -   false   false
2022-01-11 16:35:02.695 28084-28146/com.kenetic.savepass I/PassAdapter: id equality checked -   Service_name_11     access value passed -   false   false
2022-01-11 16:35:02.695 28084-28146/com.kenetic.savepass I/PassAdapter: id equality checked -   Service_name_10     access value passed -   false   false
2022-01-11 16:35:02.695 28084-28146/com.kenetic.savepass I/PassAdapter: id equality checked -   Service_name_9      access value passed -   false   false
2022-01-11 16:35:02.695 28084-28146/com.kenetic.savepass I/PassAdapter: id equality checked -   Service_name_8      access value passed -   false   false
2022-01-11 16:35:02.695 28084-28146/com.kenetic.savepass I/PassAdapter: id equality checked -   Service_name_7      access value passed -   false   false
2022-01-11 16:35:02.695 28084-28146/com.kenetic.savepass I/PassAdapter: id equality checked -   Service_name_6      access value passed -   false   false
2022-01-11 16:35:02.695 28084-28146/com.kenetic.savepass I/PassAdapter: id equality checked -   Service_name_5      access value passed -   false   false
2022-01-11 16:35:02.695 28084-28146/com.kenetic.savepass I/PassAdapter: id equality checked -   Service_name_4      access value passed -   false   false
2022-01-11 16:35:02.695 28084-28146/com.kenetic.savepass I/PassAdapter: id equality checked -   Service_name_3      access value passed -   false   false
2022-01-11 16:35:02.695 28084-28146/com.kenetic.savepass I/PassAdapter: id equality checked -   Service_name_2      access value passed -   false   false
2022-01-11 16:35:02.695 28084-28146/com.kenetic.savepass I/PassAdapter: id equality checked -   Service_name_1      access value passed -   true    true

    • look at the first and the last entries. this is the entries they have two trues those are for the olditem and newitem from the diffutil object. lets make another change -

2022-01-11 16:35:26.283 28084-28153/com.kenetic.savepass I/PassAdapter: id equality checked -   Service_name_1      access value passed -   true    false
2022-01-11 16:35:26.283 28084-28153/com.kenetic.savepass I/PassAdapter: id equality checked -   Service_name_2      access value passed -   false   false
2022-01-11 16:35:26.283 28084-28153/com.kenetic.savepass I/PassAdapter: id equality checked -   Service_name_3      access value passed -   false   false
2022-01-11 16:35:26.283 28084-28153/com.kenetic.savepass I/PassAdapter: id equality checked -   Service_name_4      access value passed -   false   false
2022-01-11 16:35:26.284 28084-28153/com.kenetic.savepass I/PassAdapter: id equality checked -   Service_name_5      access value passed -   false   false
2022-01-11 16:35:26.284 28084-28153/com.kenetic.savepass I/PassAdapter: id equality checked -   Service_name_6      access value passed -   false   false
2022-01-11 16:35:26.284 28084-28153/com.kenetic.savepass I/PassAdapter: id equality checked -   Service_name_7      access value passed -   false   false
2022-01-11 16:35:26.284 28084-28153/com.kenetic.savepass I/PassAdapter: id equality checked -   Service_name_8      access value passed -   false   false
2022-01-11 16:35:26.284 28084-28153/com.kenetic.savepass I/PassAdapter: id equality checked -   Service_name_9      access value passed -   false   false
2022-01-11 16:35:26.284 28084-28153/com.kenetic.savepass I/PassAdapter: id equality checked -   Service_name_10     access value passed -   false   false
2022-01-11 16:35:26.284 28084-28153/com.kenetic.savepass I/PassAdapter: id equality checked -   Service_name_11     access value passed -   false   false
2022-01-11 16:35:26.284 28084-28153/com.kenetic.savepass I/PassAdapter: id equality checked -   Service_name_12     access value passed -   false   false
2022-01-11 16:35:26.284 28084-28153/com.kenetic.savepass I/PassAdapter: id equality checked -   Service_name_12     access value passed -   false   false
2022-01-11 16:35:26.284 28084-28153/com.kenetic.savepass I/PassAdapter: id equality checked -   Service_name_11     access value passed -   false   false
2022-01-11 16:35:26.284 28084-28153/com.kenetic.savepass I/PassAdapter: id equality checked -   Service_name_10     access value passed -   false   false
2022-01-11 16:35:26.284 28084-28153/com.kenetic.savepass I/PassAdapter: id equality checked -   Service_name_9      access value passed -   false   false
2022-01-11 16:35:26.284 28084-28153/com.kenetic.savepass I/PassAdapter: id equality checked -   Service_name_8      access value passed -   false   false
2022-01-11 16:35:26.284 28084-28153/com.kenetic.savepass I/PassAdapter: id equality checked -   Service_name_7      access value passed -   false   false
2022-01-11 16:35:26.284 28084-28153/com.kenetic.savepass I/PassAdapter: id equality checked -   Service_name_6      access value passed -   false   false
2022-01-11 16:35:26.284 28084-28153/com.kenetic.savepass I/PassAdapter: id equality checked -   Service_name_5      access value passed -   false   false
2022-01-11 16:35:26.284 28084-28153/com.kenetic.savepass I/PassAdapter: id equality checked -   Service_name_4      access value passed -   false   false
2022-01-11 16:35:26.284 28084-28153/com.kenetic.savepass I/PassAdapter: id equality checked -   Service_name_3      access value passed -   false   false
2022-01-11 16:35:26.284 28084-28153/com.kenetic.savepass I/PassAdapter: id equality checked -   Service_name_2      access value passed -   false   false
2022-01-11 16:35:26.284 28084-28153/com.kenetic.savepass I/PassAdapter: id equality checked -   Service_name_1      access value passed -   true    false
2022-01-11 16:35:26.286 28084-28146/com.kenetic.savepass I/PassAdapter: id equality checked -   Service_name_1      access value passed -   false   false
2022-01-11 16:35:26.286 28084-28146/com.kenetic.savepass I/PassAdapter: id equality checked -   Service_name_2      access value passed -   false   false
2022-01-11 16:35:26.286 28084-28146/com.kenetic.savepass I/PassAdapter: id equality checked -   Service_name_3      access value passed -   false   true
2022-01-11 16:35:26.286 28084-28146/com.kenetic.savepass I/PassAdapter: id equality checked -   Service_name_4      access value passed -   false   false
2022-01-11 16:35:26.286 28084-28146/com.kenetic.savepass I/PassAdapter: id equality checked -   Service_name_5      access value passed -   false   false
2022-01-11 16:35:26.286 28084-28146/com.kenetic.savepass I/PassAdapter: id equality checked -   Service_name_6      access value passed -   false   false
2022-01-11 16:35:26.286 28084-28146/com.kenetic.savepass I/PassAdapter: id equality checked -   Service_name_7      access value passed -   false   false
2022-01-11 16:35:26.286 28084-28146/com.kenetic.savepass I/PassAdapter: id equality checked -   Service_name_8      access value passed -   false   false
2022-01-11 16:35:26.286 28084-28146/com.kenetic.savepass I/PassAdapter: id equality checked -   Service_name_9      access value passed -   false   false
2022-01-11 16:35:26.286 28084-28146/com.kenetic.savepass I/PassAdapter: id equality checked -   Service_name_10     access value passed -   false   false
2022-01-11 16:35:26.286 28084-28146/com.kenetic.savepass I/PassAdapter: id equality checked -   Service_name_11     access value passed -   false   false
2022-01-11 16:35:26.286 28084-28146/com.kenetic.savepass I/PassAdapter: id equality checked -   Service_name_12     access value passed -   false   false
2022-01-11 16:35:26.286 28084-28146/com.kenetic.savepass I/PassAdapter: id equality checked -   Service_name_12     access value passed -   false   false
2022-01-11 16:35:26.286 28084-28146/com.kenetic.savepass I/PassAdapter: id equality checked -   Service_name_11     access value passed -   false   false
2022-01-11 16:35:26.286 28084-28146/com.kenetic.savepass I/PassAdapter: id equality checked -   Service_name_10     access value passed -   false   false
2022-01-11 16:35:26.286 28084-28146/com.kenetic.savepass I/PassAdapter: id equality checked -   Service_name_9      access value passed -   false   false
2022-01-11 16:35:26.286 28084-28146/com.kenetic.savepass I/PassAdapter: id equality checked -   Service_name_8      access value passed -   false   false
2022-01-11 16:35:26.286 28084-28146/com.kenetic.savepass I/PassAdapter: id equality checked -   Service_name_7      access value passed -   false   false
2022-01-11 16:35:26.286 28084-28146/com.kenetic.savepass I/PassAdapter: id equality checked -   Service_name_6      access value passed -   false   false
2022-01-11 16:35:26.286 28084-28146/com.kenetic.savepass I/PassAdapter: id equality checked -   Service_name_5      access value passed -   false   false
2022-01-11 16:35:26.286 28084-28146/com.kenetic.savepass I/PassAdapter: id equality checked -   Service_name_4      access value passed -   false   false
2022-01-11 16:35:26.286 28084-28146/com.kenetic.savepass I/PassAdapter: id equality checked -   Service_name_3      access value passed -   false   true
2022-01-11 16:35:26.287 28084-28146/com.kenetic.savepass I/PassAdapter: id equality checked -   Service_name_2      access value passed -   false   false
2022-01-11 16:35:26.287 28084-28146/com.kenetic.savepass I/PassAdapter: id equality checked -   Service_name_1      access value passed -   false   false

here, there are two changes occouring simultaneously. the initial access granted is being revoked and chnaged to false. then, new access is being granted. here since 2 changes are being made, they are being detected.
```

fragment code -

```
package com.kenetic.savepass.fragments

import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.asLiveData
import androidx.navigation.fragment.findNavController
import com.kenetic.savepass.databinding.FragmentSetPasswordBinding
import com.kenetic.savepass.password.data.AppDataStore

class SetPasswordFragment : Fragment() {
    private val TAG = "SetPasswordFragmentVKP"

    private lateinit var binding: FragmentSetPasswordBinding

    private lateinit var appDataStore: AppDataStore
    private lateinit var storedPassword: String

    private var _symbolsVisibility = MutableLiveData(View.INVISIBLE)
    val symbolsVisibility: MutableLiveData<Int> get() = _symbolsVisibility

    private var _passwordMatchVisibility = MutableLiveData(View.INVISIBLE)
    val passwordMatchVisibility: MutableLiveData<Int> get() = _passwordMatchVisibility

    private var _passwordIncorrectVisibility = MutableLiveData(View.INVISIBLE)
    val passwordIncorrectVisibility: MutableLiveData<Int> get() = _passwordIncorrectVisibility

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        binding = FragmentSetPasswordBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        binding.setPasswordFragment = this
        binding.lifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        appDataStore = AppDataStore(requireContext())
        appDataStore.userMasterPasswordFlow.asLiveData().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, {
            storedPassword = it
            if (it.isEmpty()) {
                binding.oldPasswordEditText.visibility = View.GONE
                _passwordIncorrectVisibility.value = View.GONE
            }
        })
        binding.saveFab.setOnClickListener { passToNextFrag() }

    }

    private lateinit var symbolMissingText: String

    private fun getSymbolCheckWarning(temp: String): String {
        symbolMissingText = ""
        val tempTruthList = listOf<Boolean>(
            hasUpperCase(temp),
            hasLowerCase(temp),
            hasSpecial(temp),
            hasNumbers(temp),
            temp.isNotEmpty()
        )
        return if (false !in tempTruthList) {
            ""
        } else {
            "*missing character types -${symbolMissingText} "
        }
    }

    private fun hasLowerCase(str: String): Boolean {
        for (i in str) {
            if (i in 'a'..'z') {
                return true
            }
        }
        symbolMissingText += " lowercase,"
        return false
    }

    private fun hasUpperCase(str: String): Boolean {
        for (i in str) {
            if (i in 'A'..'Z') {
                return true
            }
        }
        symbolMissingText += " uppercase,"
        return false
    }

    private fun hasSpecial(str: String): Boolean {
        for (i in str) {
            if (i in "`!@#$%^&*()_-+={[}]|\\:;\"'<,>.?/") {
                return true
            }
        }
        symbolMissingText += " special,"
        return false
    }

    private fun hasNumbers(str: String): Boolean {
        for (i in str) {
            if (i in '0'..'9') {
                return true
            }
        }
        symbolMissingText += " numbers,"
        return false
    }

    private fun getLengthWarningString(str: String): String {
        return if (str.length in 9..31) "" else {
            "*length should be between 8-32 characters"
        }
    }

    private fun setNewPassWarning(): Boolean {
        val str = binding.setNewPasswordEditText.text.toString()
        val warningText = getSymbolCheckWarning(str) + getLengthWarningString(str)
        Log.i(TAG, "warningText = $warningText")
        return if (warningText.isEmpty()) {
            _symbolsVisibility.value = View.INVISIBLE
            true
        } else {
            binding.setNewTextView.text = warningText
            _symbolsVisibility.value = View.VISIBLE
            false
        }
    }

    private fun matchCheck(): Boolean {
        return if (binding.setNewPasswordEditText.text.toString() == binding.confirmNewPasswordEditText.text.toString()) {
            _passwordMatchVisibility.value = View.INVISIBLE
            true
        } else {
            _passwordMatchVisibility.value = View.VISIBLE
            false
        }
    }

    private fun incorrectCheck(): Boolean {
        return if (binding.oldPasswordEditText.text.toString() != storedPassword) {
            _passwordIncorrectVisibility.value = View.VISIBLE
            false
        } else {
            _passwordIncorrectVisibility.value = View.INVISIBLE
            true
        }
    }

    private fun passToNextFrag() {
        val tempTruthList = listOf(setNewPassWarning(), matchCheck(), incorrectCheck())
        if (false !in tempTruthList) {
            appDataStore.editMasterPassword(
                binding.setNewPasswordEditText.text.toString(),
                requireContext()
            )
            nextScreen()

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "retry again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }

    private fun nextScreen() {
        Log.i(TAG,"next screen called")
        this@SetPasswordFragment.findNavController()
            .navigate(
                SetPasswordFragmentDirections
                    .actionSetPasswordFragmentToPassListFragment()
            )
    }
}
```

adapter code -

```
package com.kenetic.savepass.adapters

import android.util.Log
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DiffUtil
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.ListAdapter
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.kenetic.savepass.R
import com.kenetic.savepass.databinding.PassListBinding
import com.kenetic.savepass.password.PassEnum.Access
import com.kenetic.savepass.password.PasswordData

private const val TAG = "PassAdapter"

class PassAdapter(private val fingerChecker: (PasswordData, Access) -> Unit) :
    ListAdapter<PasswordData, PassAdapter.PassViewHolder>(diffCallBack) {


    class PassViewHolder(
        private val binding: PassListBinding,
        private val fingerChecker: (PasswordData, Access) -> Unit
    ) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

        fun bind(passwordData: PasswordData) {
            Log.i(TAG, "bind called")
            binding.isAppOrWebImageView.setImageResource(
                if (passwordData.isAnApplication) {
                    R.drawable.is_application_icon_24
                } else {
                    R.drawable.is_website_icon_24
                }
            )
            binding.serviceNameTextView.text = passwordData.serviceName

            if (passwordData.access) {
                Log.i(TAG, "access has been given")
                binding.apply {
                    servicePasswordTextView.text = passwordData.servicePassword
                    showImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_hide_20)
                    showImageView.setOnClickListener {
                        fingerChecker(passwordData, Access.HIDE)
                    }
                }
            } else {
                Log.i(TAG, "access has been denied")
                binding.showImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_show_20)
                binding.servicePasswordTextView.text = "**********"
                binding.showImageView.setOnClickListener {
                    fingerChecker(passwordData, Access.SHOW)
                }
            }

            binding.securityTypeImageView.setImageResource(
                if (passwordData.useFingerPrint) {
                    R.drawable.fingerprint_20
                } else {
                    R.drawable.password_20
                }
            )

            binding.deleteImageView.setOnClickListener {
                fingerChecker(passwordData, Access.DELETE)

            }
            binding.editImageView.setOnClickListener {
                Log.d(TAG, "edit image onClick working")
                fingerChecker(passwordData, Access.EDIT)
            }
        }
    }

    companion object {
        private val diffCallBack = object : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<PasswordData>() {
            override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: PasswordData, newItem: PasswordData): Boolean {
                Log.i(
                    TAG,
                    "id equality checked -\t${oldItem.serviceName}\t\taccess value passed - \t${oldItem.access}\t\t${newItem.access}"
                )
                return oldItem.id == newItem.id
            }

            override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: PasswordData, newItem: PasswordData): Boolean {
                return (oldItem == newItem && oldItem.access == newItem.access)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): PassViewHolder {
        return PassViewHolder(
            PassListBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)), fingerChecker
        )
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: PassViewHolder, position: Int) {
        Log.i(TAG, "access for $position = ${getItem(position).access}")
        holder.bind(getItem(position))
    }
}
```

data class used -

```
package com.kenetic.savepass.password

import androidx.room.ColumnInfo
import androidx.room.Entity
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey

@Entity(tableName = "password_data")
data class PasswordData(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val id: Int = 0,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "service_name") var serviceName: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "service_password") var servicePassword: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "is_an_application") var isAnApplication: Boolean = false,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "use_finger_print") var useFingerPrint: Boolean = true,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "access") var access: Boolean = false
)
```

I have tried converting my element list to a list then submitting that list to the adapter class, saving the value of the list to another variable and submitting that variable, changing the diffutil object functions to scan each element and then return the value, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of submitting a list of a self defined data class which comprises of multiple variables within itself, what we can do is to submit an id (integer) list and then in the onBind section of the adapter class, get the content by using a view model function and then bind the items using the content received from that function. the function can look something like -

```
fun getById(id:Int): Flow<TasksData> = tasksDao.getById(id)
```

where getById is something like -

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM task_data where id = :id")
fun getById(id: Int): Flow<TasksData>
```

then, since it is returning a continuous flow, we can set an observer in the onBind within the adapter such that the ui is updated every time a data change is detected. something like -

```
taskViewmodel.getById(getItem(position)).aslivedata.observe{
    holder.bind(it)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Where are you setting the adapter to your RecyclerView?

Try this:

```
binding.recyclerView.adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
```